# I have a LEXAR 16GB USB that is partitioned and only showing a capacity of 200MB

Tags: usb

I'm trying to maximize the use of a USB thumb drive that I have. Can someone help me with the steps to partition it the correct way?

Comment: Is the drive formatted as fat32?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your thumb drive is getting reported as having a GUID Partition Table by the OS. You can confirm this by checking the drive properties Volumes tab and see what the reported Partition style is listed as. If its GPT you need to reformat it using command prompt. You didn't mention which OS you're using so I'm assuming you're on Windows. Follow the steps below:

1. Open command prompt (run it as administrator), type "diskpart" and hit enter.
2. Type list disk to see your disks and find the number of your disk (You can go to Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management and verify the Disk number of the USB drive).
3. Then type "select disk 6" to select your disk (replace the 5 with your USB disk number)
4. Type "clean" and enter. This will remove all the volumes on the selected drive and any data you have on the disk will be lost too.
5. Now type "create partition primary" to create a new partition
6. Select the partition by typing "select partition 1"
7. Type  "format fs=fat32 quick" to format the new partition and you're done.

Unplug the drive and plug back to your computer. Now it should report the actual disk size

Comment: Why do you think the USB stick has a GPT?

Comment: Similar thing happened with my SanDisk USB drive. 16GB drive showing 200 MB space. Anyways, I edited my answer a bit and added some information so that OP can confirm that his/her drive has GPT.